Problems with Workers, Cloudflare and Keystatic
I'm currently developing a platform for open and free education with keystatic and Astro, ideal
We created a collection for each major in the university, each of them can create a semester and the semester has a array field to create his specify subjects, all that information is saved in a json file for each collection
keystatic config file
In each post to be write in keystatic you can select him for what major, semester and subject it belongs to. for create the fields.select of that I use a script that obtain the collection and create the fields, that's exported and at the end is used in the keystatic config.
My workers in Cloudflare exceed the limit of 1MiB, how can I optimize that?
Error: Failed to publish your Function. Got error: Your Worker exceeded the size limit of 1 MiB. Refer to the Workers documentation (https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/observability/errors/#errors-on-worker-upload) for more details.

We use to have hardcoded  in Typescript Files all the majors, semesters and subjects, but we think that isn't realiable at long term, and isn't that user-friendly.
That solution didn't causes any problem with workers.

You have to split you app in several sub-workers, chaining them

It looks like you're on a free plan. If you upgrade to Workers Paid ($5/mo), the limit increases to 10MB: https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/platform/limits/

You can debug the output of the npm build command which write to .cloudflare/ directory I think.

@pierpy thank you for respond, can you give me a clue about how can i do that or where can i check more documentation

Start here: https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/platform/limits/#worker-to-worker-subrequests. Anyway, without seeing your code, I cannot give other help
